# Unable to eval string with '<' in ruby

Tags: ruby, interpolation

I have an XML file with some ruby conditions in it. I want to read the file and ***eval*** it before using the xml content.

To simplify, here is a test case.

```
str1='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
str2='if 1+1 == 2 then "yes" end'
eval(str1)
```

eval(str2) always works but not str1. Im getting the below error.

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 ^
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            ^
(repl):5:in `eval'
(repl):5:in `<main>'
```

i want to escape the '<' and '?' and such symbols because i can't use single quote to disable interpolation. Because the xml will contain some ruby conditions which are to be executed upon ***eval***.

Appreciate any help

**EDIT:**
Please check the first line of the post. It says 'xml file with ruby condition in it'. I wanted to evaluate the conditions.

As we embed ruby code inside double-quoted string to evaluate/interpolate it, i thought i could do this is by prefixing or suffixing to make it a valid ruby expression. (e.b str1="a=#{str1}" or something similar before eval). Example i gave is an excerpt of it.

Comment: Do you know what `eval` does? If so, what kind of result were you expecting from evaling the first string?

Comment: "It says 'xml file with ruby condition in it'. I wanted to evaluate the conditions." - then evaluate __only the conditions__. Don't evaluate xml markup as ruby. That's why you get the errors.

Answer (score 3):

[`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) expects a string with expression representing **valid Ruby code**.

Comment: I think he wants to do xml templating (and therefore should use ERB), but I'm too lazy to confirm this and write an answer. Here's some free rep if you want :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i think it would be easier for me to remove the answer than to expand it.. P.S. feels unusual to see your updated avatar - I remember your old one ever since started activity here hehe :)

Comment: Yeah, that one was too old. Plus, there was some dude in the background :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was regularly laughing because of his facial expression :D

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think erb might be the right choice. But i was thinking that as we embed ruby code inside double-quote to evaluate/interpolate it, i could also do this by prefixing or suffixing to make it a valid ruby expression. (e.b str1="a=#{str1}" or something similar before eval)

Comment: @PragalathanM evaluate != interpolate